# Nifi - putFile failure - file with the same name already exists

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a json array which needs to be processed.

> { "events": [ "start", "stop", "restart", "retry" ] }

For each event, invoke http API and log response to a file.

```
1. Json Data -> SplitJson ( To split the json array )
2. SplitJson -> ExtractText ( To extract the array element )
3. invokeHttp -> putFile (Same end point but param will be different based on the extractedText from json)
```

Here, I expect different files to be created for each invokeHttp response. But, the 1st event response works fine and 2nd event http response tries to create a file with the same name and fails with error.

How to achieve this?

Also, How to process extractText response in parallel?

Comment: You have options under the putfile to ignore, fail, and replace when name conflicts happen. You could I imagine just change the name of the flowfile before attempting the put.

Comment: @edjm, Replace will delete the existing and create with the new one. I want a separate file for each as the events are different.